# How to have WebDriverWait return element instead of boolean in Python using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Right now, I have a method that will wait until an element is visible using:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, seconds).until(lambda s: s.find_element_by_xpath(path).is_displayed())
```

This works properly; however, it returns a boolean, rather than the element that it found.  I would like it to return that element once it is found.  I am doing this with the following:

```
def waituntil(path, seconds):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, seconds).until(lambda s: s.find_element_by_xpath(path).is_displayed())
    ret = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)
    return ret
```

Sure, this works.  Unfortunately, it requires Selenium to find the same element twice, though, which adds waiting time (no matter how small).  Is there a way I can return a web element using a waituntil (or similar functionality) by finding an element only once?  So something that would allow the following:

```
ret = WebDriverWait(self.driver, seconds).until(lambda s: s.find_element_by_xpath(path).is_displayed())
ret.click()
```

I'm currently using:

```
Python 2.7
Windows 7
Selenium 2.4.4
Firefox 35.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located`.

Based on [the unofficial docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
ret = WebDriverWait(self.driver, seconds).until(
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path)))
ret.click()
```

(Left out other imports and initialization for clarity, since you seem to have that stuff working. See the earlier link if you're running into issues.)